# How do I fix default CakePHP routing on a "baked" MVC?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, cakephp, routes

I just set up a database according to CakePHP's conventions, ran the "bake" scripts for models, controllers and views, and made sure the path was set up correctly.

When I go to the following style of URL:

```
http://BASEURL/app/controller_name
```

I get the expected list view for that controller, but all the links generated by baked pages are in the format I expect to see:

```
http://BASEURL/controller_name
```

which gives me a 404.  Interestingly enough, this:

```
http://BASEURL/app/
```

gives me:

```
Missing Method in AppController
Error: The action index is not defined in controller AppController
Error: Create AppController::index() in file: app/controllers/app_controller.php.
```

but this:

http://BASEURL/

gives me the default index page.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Everything else is just as created by default and the bake scripts.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Please let me know if there's ANYTHING I can clarify or show an example of.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? Do you have your BASEURL setup to point to /www/ or /www/app/? When you navigate to http://BASEURL/ do the stylesheets and images load?

Comment: I think you're getting a little confused.  When you goto http://somesite.com/app/model/action, it's passing the request off to the default AppController.  You wouldn't be seeing this error if you used http://somesite.com/MyApp/model/action.  It's just that you chose a prefix that had an existing controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your virtualhost or doc-root points to the app folder, and not its parent.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this guy had a similar problem, and the solution was in making the base directory something other than app.

http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/msg/5fba6c41a505ed48?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I just had have the same problem of danieltalsky , i fix it with this response:

> ............... " I've gotten the same problem when I put the entire
>   application into a directory that contain the words:
>
> "app"
>
> or
>
> "cake"
>
> If your directory's real name is "myapp" try changing it for
>   "mysoftware" and reload again, there is no necessary to alter
>   .htaccess files.
>
> ............... "

it's from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cake-php/AqLkqcztdHE/SO0FpUFsul8J.

Lucky